# VSCode ImportError: No module named web3

Tags: python, pip, visual-studio-code

I have Python3 and Python2 in my ubuntu 16.04. naturally, I install pip3 and pip. But When I use VScode to run my python3 code, it can't find my package! I don't find where to set the package path. I need help, thanks!

```
[Running] python "source/pyweb3.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source/pyweb3.py", line 5, in <module>
    import web3
ImportError: No module named web3

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.059 seconds
```

Here are the package information of my pip and pip3 :

```
ubuntu:/source$ pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ----------------------
                  …
virtualenv                    15.2.0
Werkzeug                      0.14.1
wheel                         0.29.0
wrapt                         1.10.11
                  …

ubuntu:/source$ pip3 list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ----------------------
                  …
virtualenv                    15.2.0
web3                          4.2.1
websockets                    4.0.1
                  …
```

Here are the information of my pip and pip3 :

```
ubuntu:/source$ pip3 --version
pip 10.0.1 from /home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

ubuntu:/source$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, it's the problem of the extension: Python. Just press F1 and input: select Interpreter to switch Python3, the problem is fixed.